# How to make image zoom in & out with mouse wheel in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I want to zoom in & out an image in blazor on asp.net.

As I use for Google Maps, I want to move the image position by zooming and dragging the image with the mouse wheel.(I want to use an image file, not a Google map.)

[image: Example of use]

Is there a way to zoom in, zoom out and drag specific images in blazor?

Comment: This is the impossible with the image same as a google map

Comment: If you need some different example the check this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sapnabeniwal/move-mouse-on-image-for-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-effect/

Comment: i don't want a google map. i want a image.

Comment: For this kind of interactivity, I recommend using JavaScript.

Answer (score 14):

***Note:***

- I would only use this on [**BlazorWasm**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#blazor-webassembly) and not [**BlazorServer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#blazor-server) because there might be quite a bit of lag if the network is slow.
- It is probably easier to just use JavaScript and/or [JavaScript interoperability (JS interop)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but for this example I decided **not to use** JS Interop.

This component enables you to *zoom* by pressing `shift` while `mouse wheel` up (zoom out) or `mouse wheel` down (zoom in) and move the image by pressing `mouse button 1` down while moving. (***it's more panning than dragging it***)

***Restriction in Blazor:*** (*at the time of writing this*)

- The biggest issue at the moment is not having access to the mouse `OffsetX` and `OffsetY` within the html element as [described here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8241) and [also here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12259), so the moving of the image has to be done using CSS only.
- The reason I used ***Shift*** for scrolling is because scrolling is not being blocked or disabled as [described here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17358) even with `@onscroll:stopPropagation`, `@onwheel:stopPropagation`, `@onmousewheel:stopPropagation` and/or `@onscroll:preventDefault`, `@onwheel:preventDefault`, `@onmousewheel:preventDefault` set on the parent `mainImageContainer` element. The screen will still scroll left and right if the content is wider than the viewable page.

***Solution:***

The Zooming part is pretty straight forward, all you need to do is set the `transform:scale(n);` property in the `@onmousewheel` event.

The moving of the image is a bit more complex because there is no reference to where the mouse pointer is in relation to the image or element boundaries. (*OffsetX* and *OffsetY*)

The only thing we can determine is if a mouse button is pressed and then calculate what direction the mouse is moving in `left`, `right`, `up` or `down`.

The idea is then to move the position of element with the image by setting the `top` and `left` CSS values as percentages.

This component code:

```
@using System.Text;

<div id="mainImageContainer" style="display: block;width:@($"{ImageWidthInPx}px");height:@($"{ImageHeightInPx}px");overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="imageMover"
         @onmousewheel="MouseWheelZooming"
         style="@MoveImageStyle">
        <div id="imageContainer"
             @onmousemove="MouseMoving"
             style="@ZoomImageStyle">
            @*this div is used just for moving around when zoomed*@
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@if (ShowResetButton)
{
    <div style="display:block">
        <button @onclick="ResetImgage">Reset</button>
    </div>
}

@code{

    /// <summary>
    /// The path or url of the image
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public string ImageUrlPath { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The width of the image
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public int ImageWidthInPx { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The height of the image
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public int ImageHeightInPx { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set to true to show the reset button
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public bool ShowResetButton { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the amount the image is scaled by, default is 0.1f
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public double DefaultScaleBy { get; set; } = 0.1f;

    /// <summary>
    /// The Maximum the image can scale to, default = 5f
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public double ScaleToMaximum { get; set; } = 5f;

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the speed at which the image is moved by, default 2.
    /// 2 or 3 seems to work best.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter]
    public double DefaultMoveBy { get; set; } = 2;

    //defaults
    double _CurrentScale = 1.0f;
    double _PositionLeft = 0;
    double _PositionTop = 0;
    double _OldClientX = 0;
    double _OldClientY = 0;
    double _DefaultMinPosition = 0;//to the top and left
    double _DefaultMaxPosition = 0;//to the right and down

    //the default settings used to display the image in the child div
    private Dictionary<string, string> _ImageContainerStyles;
    Dictionary<string, string> ImageContainerStyles
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ImageContainerStyles == null)
            {
                _ImageContainerStyles = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                _ImageContainerStyles.Add("width", "100%");
                _ImageContainerStyles.Add("height", "100%");
                _ImageContainerStyles.Add("position", "relative");
                _ImageContainerStyles.Add("background-size", "contain");
                _ImageContainerStyles.Add("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
                _ImageContainerStyles.Add("background-position", "50% 50%");
                _ImageContainerStyles.Add("background-image", $"URL({ImageUrlPath})");
            }
            return _ImageContainerStyles;
        }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> _MovingContainerStyles;
    Dictionary<string, string> MovingContainerStyles
    {
        get
        {
            if (_MovingContainerStyles == null)
            {
                InvokeAsync(ResetImgage);
            }
            return _MovingContainerStyles;
        }
    }

    protected async Task ResetImgage()
    {
        _PositionLeft = 0;
        _PositionTop = 0;
        _DefaultMinPosition = 0;
        _DefaultMaxPosition = 0;
        _CurrentScale = 1.0f;

        _MovingContainerStyles = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        _MovingContainerStyles.Add("width", "100%");
        _MovingContainerStyles.Add("height", "100%");
        _MovingContainerStyles.Add("position", "relative");
        _MovingContainerStyles.Add("left", $"{_PositionLeft}%");
        _MovingContainerStyles.TryAdd("top", $"{_PositionTop}%");
    
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    string ZoomImageStyle { get => DictionaryToCss(ImageContainerStyles); }
    string MoveImageStyle { get => DictionaryToCss(MovingContainerStyles); }


    private string DictionaryToCss(Dictionary<string, string> styleDictionary)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var kvp in styleDictionary.AsEnumerable())
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}:{1};", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }


    protected async void MouseMoving(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //if the mouse button 1 is not down exit the function
        if (e.Buttons != 1)
        {
            _OldClientX = e.ClientX;
            _OldClientY = e.ClientY;
            return;
        }

        //get the % of the current scale to move by at least the default move speed plus any scaled changes
        //basically the bigger the image the faster it moves..
        double scaleFrac = (_CurrentScale / ScaleToMaximum);
        double scaleMove = (DefaultMoveBy * (DefaultMoveBy * scaleFrac));

        //moving mouse right
        if (_OldClientX < e.ClientX)
        {
            if ((_PositionLeft - DefaultMoveBy) <= _DefaultMaxPosition)
            {
                _PositionLeft += scaleMove;
            }
        }

        //moving mouse left
        if (_OldClientX > e.ClientX)
        {
            //if (_DefaultMinPosition < (_PositionLeft - DefaultMoveBy))
            if ((_PositionLeft + DefaultMoveBy) >= _DefaultMinPosition)
            {
                _PositionLeft -= scaleMove;
            }
        }

        //moving mouse down
        if (_OldClientY < e.ClientY)
        {
            //if ((_PositionTop + DefaultMoveBy) <= _DefaultMaxPosition)
            if ((_PositionTop - DefaultMoveBy) <= _DefaultMaxPosition)
            {
                _PositionTop += scaleMove;
            }
        }

        //moving mouse up
        if (_OldClientY > e.ClientY)
        {
            //if ((_PositionTop - DefaultMoveBy) > _DefaultMinPosition)
            if ((_PositionTop + DefaultMoveBy) >= _DefaultMinPosition)
            {
                _PositionTop -= scaleMove;
            }
        }

        _OldClientX = e.ClientX;
        _OldClientY = e.ClientY;

        await UpdateScaleAndPosition();
    }

    async Task<double> IncreaseScale()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //increase the scale first then calculate the max and min positions
            _CurrentScale += DefaultScaleBy;
            double scaleFrac = (_CurrentScale / ScaleToMaximum);
            double scaleDiff = (DefaultMoveBy + (DefaultMoveBy * scaleFrac));
            double scaleChange = DefaultMoveBy + scaleDiff;
            _DefaultMaxPosition += scaleChange;
            _DefaultMinPosition -= scaleChange;

            return _CurrentScale;
        });
    }

    async Task<double> DecreaseScale()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _CurrentScale -= DefaultScaleBy;
           
            double scaleFrac = (_CurrentScale / ScaleToMaximum);
            double scaleDiff = (DefaultMoveBy + (DefaultMoveBy * scaleFrac));
            double scaleChange = DefaultMoveBy + scaleDiff;
            _DefaultMaxPosition -= scaleChange;
            _DefaultMinPosition += scaleChange;//DefaultMoveBy;

            //fix descaling, move the image back into view when descaling (zoomin out)
            if (_CurrentScale <= 1)
            {
                _PositionLeft = 0;
                _PositionTop = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                //left can not be more than max position
                _PositionLeft = (_DefaultMaxPosition < _PositionLeft) ? _DefaultMaxPosition : _PositionLeft;

                //top can not be more than max position
                _PositionTop = (_DefaultMaxPosition < _PositionTop) ? _DefaultMaxPosition : _PositionTop;

                //left can not be less than min position
                _PositionLeft = (_DefaultMinPosition > _PositionLeft) ? _DefaultMinPosition : _PositionLeft;

                //top can not be less than min position
                _PositionTop = (_DefaultMinPosition > _PositionTop) ? _DefaultMinPosition : _PositionTop;
            }
            return _CurrentScale;
        });
    }

    protected async void MouseWheelZooming(WheelEventArgs e)
    {
        //holding shift stops the page from scrolling
        if (e.ShiftKey == true)
        {
            if (e.DeltaY > 0)
            {
                _CurrentScale = ((_CurrentScale + DefaultScaleBy) >= 5) ? _CurrentScale = 5f : await IncreaseScale();
            }
            if (e.DeltaY < 0)
            {
                _CurrentScale = ((_CurrentScale - DefaultScaleBy) <= 0) ? _CurrentScale = DefaultScaleBy : await DecreaseScale();
            }

            await UpdateScaleAndPosition();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Refresh the values in the moving style dictionary that is used to position the image.
    /// </summary>    
    async Task UpdateScaleAndPosition()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (!MovingContainerStyles.TryAdd("transform", $"scale({_CurrentScale})"))
            {
                MovingContainerStyles["transform"] = $"scale({_CurrentScale})";
            }

            if (!MovingContainerStyles.TryAdd("left", $"{_PositionLeft}%"))
            {
                MovingContainerStyles["left"] = $"{_PositionLeft}%";
            }

            if (!MovingContainerStyles.TryAdd("top", $"{_PositionTop}%"))
            {
                MovingContainerStyles["top"] = $"{_PositionTop}%";
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is the usage:

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorWasmApp.Components
Welcome to your new app.

<ZoomableImageComponent ImageUrlPath="images/Capricorn.png"
                        ImageWidthInPx=400
                        ImageHeightInPx=300
                        ShowResetButton=true
                        DefaultScaleBy=0.1f />
```

and this is the result:

[image]

I only tested this in chrome on a desktop computer without touch input.

Comment: Any update with Blazor 5 and `OffsetX`, `OffsetY`, please? I had to ensure I am using `en-US` in `UpdateScaleAndPosition` method. Also, as a little tweak, you don't need to call `TryAdd` in the dictionaries, because the indexer already inserts the element if it doesn't exist:

`MovingContainerStyles["transform"] = $"scale({_CurrentScale.ToString(enUsCultureInfo)})";
MovingContainerStyles["left"] = $"{_PositionLeft.ToString(enUsCultureInfo)}%";
MovingContainerStyles["top"] = $"{_PositionTop.ToString(enUsCultureInfo)}%";`

Comment: @Nekketsu Apologies, I have not had the chance to play with the latest Blazor yet. A quick google didn't show anything new apart from using JSInterop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As far as I know, Blazor 5 has now the properties `OffsetX` and `OffsetY` in the mouse events: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-release-candidate-2/ . It was a restriction in the previous version of Blazor. You mentioned that it made the moving of the image more difficult. I was looking forward for a solution using these now available properties, `OffsetX` and `OffsetY`.